# Mysql rank over function

Tags: mysql

I am using the below query in MySQL workbench, and I am getting an error near the rank over function. I think MySQL may not support support Rank() over function. hence please can anyone help to run this one successfully?

```
select STORE_CODE, 'GBP', "SALES WITHOUT VAT", 'UK' from(
select STORE_CODE, "SALES WITHOUT VAT", RANK() OVER(ORDER BY "SALES WITHOUT VAT" DESC) AS RANK 
 from( select store_code, sum("SALES WITHOUT VAT") as "SALES WITHOUT VAT" 
       from( select c_site AS STORE_CODE, case when c_currency = 'GBP' then A_SALES_EXVAT_REAL 
       when c_currency = 'EUR' then round(A_SALES_EXVAT_REAL * ukurs ,3) end as "SALES WITHOUT VAT" 
       from kf_move01.salesticket_line left outer join
       (select ukurs, to_date(99999999-gdatu), year(to_date(99999999-gdatu)) as year, month(to_date(99999999-gdatu)) as month 
       from "KF_MOVE01"."TCURR" 
       where mandt = 201 and kurst = 'M' and tcurr = 'GBP' and fcurr = 'EUR' 
       order by 99999999-gdatu desc) as tcur 
       on tcur.year = year(d_year_month_day) and tcur.month = month(d_year_month_day) 
       where id_opco = 2 and c_comp_code in ('BQ10', 'BQ20','BQ30','BQ40') 
       and d_year_month_day between add_days(now(),-181) and add_days(now(),-1)) 
       group by store_code 
       order by 2 desc ) ) where rank <= 5;
```

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '( ORDER BY "SALES WITHOUT VAT" DESC ) FROM (SELECT' at line 6 0.000 sec Java error: SAP DBTech JDBC: [279] (at 179): group function is nested: line 1 col 180 (at pos 179)

Online sql checker error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: '( ORDER BY "SALES WITHOUT VAT" DESC ) AS RANK from( ' at line 10

Comment: MySQL Workbench just sends your query to MySQL so it doesn't have to support any MySQL functions and won't give you a SQL error. That error is from MySQL itself.

Comment: We can't help you unless you provide us with the complete error message

Comment: but it is not working. its giving me a syntax error.

Comment: eclipse error:group function is nested

Comment: Error in mysql: Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(         ORDER BY  "SALES WITHOUT VAT" DESC )         FROM              (SELECT' at line 6              0.000 sec

Java error: SAP DBTech JDBC: [279] (at 179): group function is nested: line 1 col 180 (at pos 179)

Online sql checker error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: '( ORDER BY "SALES WITHOUT VAT" DESC ) AS RANK from( ' at line 10

Comment: and from mysql : i am getting syntax error near the OVER saying missing closing parenthesis

Comment: That is the error one would expect if your MySQL version would not support window functions. So make sure you are actually using MySQL 8+ (or MariaDB 10.2+). You can check that with `select @@version`.

Comment: @S.Pal Check the version of MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in fact using MySQL 8.0, there are a couple of things going on here.

It's okay to have a column alias enclosed in double quotes, `"SALES WITHOUT VAT"`, but you can't refer to it in double quotes when selecting that same column from your subquery. You have to use backticks, or MySQL will think you are literally selecting the string called "SALES WITHOUT VAT".

In order to get the rank function working, try moving your `order by` to the end of the query.

```
select STORE_CODE, 'GBP', `SALES WITHOUT VAT`, 'UK' from(
select STORE_CODE, `SALES WITHOUT VAT`, RANK() over w AS `RANK`
.
.
.
) window w as (order by `SALES WITHOUT VAT` desc))
where `RANK` <=5;
```

playing around with this SQL fiddle may help.

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/28ZF6xdoWsVvH6JTNsFdQo/3